# UITableView bottom separator inset - Strange behaviour in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uikit

My app contains a `UITableView` which has section footers. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the tableView, sometimes a separator inset appears between the last cell and the tableFooter. This behaviour is inconsistent.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to force this separator to always appear or never appear? Did any of you noticed this same inconsistent behaviour? Seems like a bug to me.

EDIT
I'm using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *footer = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    footer.font = [footer.font fontWithSize:15];
    footer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    return footer;
}
```

but you could easily reproduce the same problem only using

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your code in `viewForFooter...`?

Comment: Did you get the solution for it ?

Comment: I would suggest that You skip the default tableView separator madness and set it to invisible:  
    [_tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  And then simply add UIView subview to each cell, which would be with frame CGRectMake(0,0,_tableview.frame.size.width,1)   and then also hide it if cell row is 0.    This way it will also be more consistent with previous iOS versions and also You can use custom separator line image (if needed..) or custom colour or inset positions from sides.

Comment: have you found the solution to this?  I am experiencing the same problem.  It sounds like implementing your own separators with a 1 pixel high UIView set at the cell bottom is only thing that works

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll have to override the standard `UIView` used as the footer.

You can do this by overriding the delegate method `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *myFooterView;

    // create a view with a label and without a line at the top etc...

    return myFooterView;
}
```

Comment: I'm already using viewForFooterInSection. Anyway, the bug is completely unrelated to that method since it happens if you use it or not.

Comment: Ah, I put my answer before you edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting inconsistent results. Maybe try to add a background to your footer view. Here is my code:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 33)];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, footerView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    label.text = @"Footer";
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [footerView addSubview:label];

    return footerView;
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I added more images to show to issue. Same problem happens even if you set a `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a lazy way of doing it but it works none the less.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifyer"];

    if (indexPath.row == tableArray.count) {
         cell.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You can't set `separatorStyle` on a single cell. And setting `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(whatever);` doesn't help.

Comment: @user32050560 I am pretty sure I set cell.separatorInset for a single cell in iOS 7 (usually the last visible cell in a section in a grouped tableview when I was hiding the rows beneath it). Are you are of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution, very easy!

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifyer"];

    cell.separatorInset = (indexPath.row == totalNumber-1) ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, INT16_MAX, 0, 0) : UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround about it:

Whenever you expect this extra separator could appear (for example, when user scrolls to the bottom like you described) - add these lines of code:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITable​View​Cell​Separator​Style​None;
tableView.separatorStyle = UITable​View​Cell​Separator​Style​Single​Line;
```

The logic is something like that: first string of code removes bottom separator, and the second one doesn't add it. It worked for me in some cases, but it is not a 100% fix.

I guess, it might be an Apple bug also, as sometimes bottom separator disappears in their 'Reminders' app.